# Regex: PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition

Tags: java, regex, string

I am not good at regex and I am trying to use `java.lang.String` `replaceAll()` method with code segments as follows

A is:

```
public class method3 {

    public static int addTwoNumbers(int one, int two){
        return one+two;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int total = addTwoNumbers(1, 3);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

to replace with B

```
null
public class method3 {
    /* some writting */
    public static int addTwoNumbers(int one, int two){
        return one+two;
    }
    /*more text*/
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int total = addTwoNumbers(1, 3);
        System.out.println(total);
    }//end of 
}
```

And this is giving me the following error

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
```

Im guessing this has something to do with the `/**/` characters?

How do you sort this and is there any other characters i need to look out for?

**EDIT: This is the error message**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 25
null
public class method2 {

    public static int addTwoNumbers(int one, int two){
        return one+two;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int total = addTwoNumbers(1, 3);
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}


                         ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    ....
```

call to replaceAll()

```
        String a = readFile(directoryToAddFile,startOfCode, endOfCode);
        String b = textarea.getText().toString();
        String content = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(directoryToAddFile));
        content = content.replaceAll(a, b);
        IOUtils.write(content, new FileOutputStream(directoryToAddFile));
```

Comment: the codes snippets are the same arent they?

Comment: It would help if you'd show the code which is failing. Yes, `*` has a special meaning in regular expressions... but it may be that regexes aren't the best approach here anyway.

Comment: Where is the call to replaceAll ?

Comment: where are you using patterns at all? I only see `System.out.println` and `one+two`.

Comment: the code is the same i am trying to replace just that it has some omments in it... this is just a simple example

Comment: this is no example. An example needs code that is failing.

Comment: @KidTempo: what would you suggest to use so instead of replaceAll()?

Comment: Why don't you print out a and b to the console to see exactly what is being captured?  Then post that here if you cannot figure it out still.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: The first two pieces of code are what A and B are

Comment: You will need to escape several of the characters.  You cannot simply replace A with B verbatim, I believe.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: yes, I have been using the debugger and checking the variables after they have been set, the only difference is that A has a white space for the first line and B has a white space at the last line

Comment: Whats this `null` doing above the method3, in 2nd code... null \\ I don't think this should be here public class method3 { /* some writting */ public static int addTwoNumbers(int one, int two){ return one+two; } /*more text*/ public static void main (String[] args){ int total = addTwoNumbers(1, 3); System.out.println(total); }//end of }

Comment: @BlackVegetable: what do you mean 'escape several of the characters'?

Comment: @flexinIT Use a replace method that does NOT use regular expressions. Parentheses "(" and ")" and others need to be escaped so regexp is not what you need. I'm writing this using my phone do i can't look up which method is more suitable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, your code attempts to analyze the "to replace" string as a regex.

To replace a string literally rather than as a regex, you can use [Pattern#quote(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

```
content = content.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(a), b);
```

Also, as a side note, you might find [String#replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) more appropriate than replaceAll in this situation.

Comment: I have tried both your suggestions about yet none of them work(well not working), I am not getting the error no more but it is not replacing any of the text for the content

Comment: In that case, the replace methods simply aren't finding your string in the other string.  That's a different question altogether though, so if you wish to ask it, create a new question rather than editing this one.  However, that's an issue easily solvable through some simple debugging.

Comment: yes, there was white space at the end of one of the strings so after i .trim() on the string it worked, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely stemming from not escaping several of the characters in what you are trying to replace, as well as what you are trying to replace it with.  Regex may not be the tool you want to use here.  From www.regular-expressions.info, the characters to be aware of are []\^$.|?*+()

Read up on that website to see the uses/limitations of regex.